# Removing Add-ins for SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, add-in, ssms

I have SQL server 2008 R2 installed.

In the past I have installed the Redgate Sql Promprt 5 add-in. It doesn't work anymore, but I still have the menu in the SQL Management Studio.

I don't see the add-in in the **Programs and features** list in windows 7, so I can't uninstall it. 
When I click on a command in the menu I get this message:

> The Add-in supporting this command could not be loaded. Do you wish
>   to remove the command?

When I choose "Yes" it removes only the selected command from the menu.

I want to completely remove the add-in from my Management Studio.

Where can I find the add-ins and where can I configure them in Management Studio 2008 R2?

If I need to remove some files to get rid of it, where could I find these files?
I looked in the installation folder and didn't find anything about add-ins...

Comment: Isn't this more a question to redgate support :)? You can try remove registry keys manually now or just download the latest evaluation of the software, install it, and after reinstall if you don't want to use it anymore.

Comment: My question is about how to manage SQL management studio Add-ins, The Redgate add-in is an example. The only way to manage the add-ins is through the operating system, or is there another way?

Comment: Ah, just open Management Studio, click on menu extras and modify your menu and toolbars like you can do in most m$ products.

Comment: The problem is not about removing toolbars, the problem is the menu that does nothing and can't be removed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### And now for the correct answer

To remove all addin from SQL Server Management Studio. Delete all keys from:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

  - SOFTWARE

    - Wow6432Node

      - Microsoft

        - Microsoft SQL Server

          - 100

            - Tools

              - Shell

                - AddIns

[image]

I didn't *ask* RedGate to slow down my SSMS with no way to disable it.

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue under 120. It seems Addins are now stored in Program Data. I renamed file but didn't help. I had to open/run SSMS in Administrator mode and this fixed it. Later I deleted the Addin from folder "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\12.0\Addins". May be you can try renaming the Addin with "_". That was the only difference in me renaming the file and SSMS in Admin mode renaming it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when loading SQL Server, an Add-in from another related application was giving that error.  I didn't need that Add-in, but couldn't remove it.  Even removing from the registry (thanks for posting that by the way) didn't work for me.  I had to uninstall and reinstall the related application (Toad for SQL Server) and the "Add-in" was no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using SSMS Tools but it kept autosaving my queries which I couldn't easily disable. Therefore I had to remove add in.

Comment: How did you remove this Add-in? I can't find any uninstall and I don't like the idea of manipulating the registry because it once caused many error  messages to appear in SSMS

Comment: how did you remove it? i also want to punt it, without playing with the registry